# How to configure tomcat and apache

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have to configure `Apache` httpd server with `Tomcat`. I have followed [this tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/ApachePlusTomcat_HowTo.html) and I am getting this error

```
D:\myproject\apache\bin>httpd -k start
httpd: Syntax error on line 560 of D:/myproject/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax e
rror on line 3 of D:/myproject/tomcat/conf/mod_jk.conf: Cannot load D:/myproject
/apache/modules/mod_jk.so into server: The specified procedure could not be foun
d.
```

I couldn't sort out first, that I was getting version error. Most probably I am trying to insert 32 bit `mod_jk` to 64 bit OS. If any one have well-configured Apache httpd server and tomcat please share it.

Comment: "The specified procedure could not be found." -> Their is no file called: "D:/myproject/apache/modules/mod_jk.so"

Comment: yes there is mod_jk.so but still it's showing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_jk obliges two substances:

mod_jk.xxx - The Apache HTTP Server module, contingent upon your working framework, it will be mod_jk.so, mod_jk.nlm or MOD_JK.SRVPGM (see the fabricate segment).

workers.properties - A record that portrays the host(s) and port(s) utilized by the specialists (Tomcat forms). A specimen workers.properties can be found under the conf registry in the source download.

Additionally as with other Apache HTTP Server modules, mod_jk ought to be initially introduced on the modules catalog of your Apache webserver, ie :/usr/lib/apache and you ought to overhaul your httpd.conf record. For More Visit http://www.pillenpalast.com/